# Compiling OpenCV 2.4.13 with Cmake and MinGW

Tags: c++, opencv, build, cmake, mingw

I got this problem when trying to compile opencv using Cmake and mingw.

for Cmake:
  sourcecode is located in "C:\CPP Libraries\OpenCV-2.4.13\opencv\sources"
  where the binaries are goint to be build is in: "C:/CPP Libraries/OpenCV-2.4.13/opencv/build/x64/mingw"

I've already used Cmake to generate the makefile.

when i run the makefile:

```
C:\CPP Libraries\OpenCV-2.4.13\opencv\build\x64\mingw>mingw32-make
```

this is the output that I get after 31%

```
[ 31%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_w32.cpp.obj
C:\CPP Libraries\OpenCV-2.4.13\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp: In function 'int icvCreateTrackbar(const char*, const char*, int*, int, CvTrackbarCallback, CvTrackbarCallback2, void*)':
C:\CPP Libraries\OpenCV-2.4.13\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1853:81: error: 'BTNS_AUTOSIZE' was not declared in this scope
                                         WS_CHILD | CCS_TOP | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE | BTNS_AUTOSIZE | BTNS_BUTTON,
                                                                                 ^
C:\CPP Libraries\OpenCV-2.4.13\opencv\sources\modules\highgui\src\window_w32.cpp:1853:97: error: 'BTNS_BUTTON' was not declared in this scope
                                         WS_CHILD | CCS_TOP | TBSTYLE_WRAPABLE | BTNS_AUTOSIZE | BTNS_BUTTON,
                                                                                                 ^
modules\highgui\CMakeFiles\opencv_highgui.dir\build.make:187: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_w32.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_w32.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2203: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone knows a solution, because i have no clue about this one.

//EDIT!

After downloaded the version from the git repository and try to build it i got these other errors.
I already try to change #define _WIN32_IE 0x0300    to    #define _WIN32_IE 0x0500
in "commctrl.h" in MinGW directory, but it didn't worl.

```
C:\CPP Libraries\OpenCV-2.4.13\Git\opencv\build\x64\mingw>mingw32-make
[  2%] Built target zlib
[  6%] Built target libtiff
[ 11%] Built target libjpeg
[ 16%] Built target libwebp
[ 19%] Built target libjasper
[ 20%] Built target libpng
[ 26%] Built target IlmImf
[ 26%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[ 26%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[ 26%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel.cpp.obj
C:\CPP Libraries\OpenCV-2.4.13\Git\opencv\modules\core\src\parallel.cpp: In function 'int cv::getThreadNum()':
C:\CPP Libraries\OpenCV-2.4.13\Git\opencv\modules\core\src\parallel.cpp:474:45: error: 'pthread_self' was not declared in this scope
     return (int)(size_t)(void*)pthread_self(); // no zero-based indexing
                                             ^
modules\core\CMakeFiles\opencv_core.dir\build.make:990: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/parallel.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:1473: recipe for target 'modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the code.

Comment: you got `1337` in your [post id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461337 "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39461337")

Comment: I'm on openCV 3.2.0 using Windows 10 and still have the problem noted here with `pthread_self()`. Seems this hasn't been fixed in later versions - assuming it is an openCV problem (vs. a MinGW problem).

Answer (score 3):

The problem (according to Artur Wieczorek) is OS version set by MinGW by default. To cure it find "commctrl.h" in MinGW directory and something like

```
 #if 0
 #define _WIN32_IE   0x0300
 #endif
```

then change it to

```
 #if 1
 #define _WIN32_IE   0x0500
 #endif
```

Comment: misc: you could've copied that code on-site (to stackoverflow.com) as text

Answer (score 1):

expanding [Le Quyen's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39468139/) answer:

You *don't need* "the git version".

The `error: 'BTNS_AUTOSIZE' was not declared in this scope` for 2.4.13 is worked around in http://code.opencv.org/issues/4087:

1. open `C:\MingW\include\commctrl.h` or equivalent.
2. search `/* define _WIN32_IE if you really want it */`
3. ***edit the text underneath so it looks like this:***

   ```
   #if 1
   #define _WIN32_IE   0x0500
   #endif
   ```

credits to Artur Wieczoek and Vit Shiryaev for the hint.

---

Why unset? I don't know but the people giving you MingW are trying [to make this clear on their wiki](http://www.mingw.org/category/wiki/w32api):

> You need to set defines _WIN32_WINDOWS, _WIN32_WINNT, WINVER and/or _WIN32_IE to the minimum platform you plan to support before including the windows.h header file. Possible values for these definitions can be found in the header w32api.h file.

Comment: Thanks! Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting something like

> "opencv/sources/module/core/src/parallel.cpp": In function "int
>   cv::getThreadNum()" ......./parallel.cpp:505:45: error: 'pthread' was
>   not declared in the scope

I tried the above suggestion to change Mingw/include/commctrl.h as:

```
#ifndef _WIN32_IE
/* define _WIN32_IE if you really want it */
#if 0                           // to 1
#define _WIN32_IE   0x0300      // to 0x0500
#endif
#endif
```

but things didn't went ahead and I was still stuck with same problem.

Then I unchecked the "WITH_PTHREADS_PF" in CMake-GUI flag list and proceeded.

Comment: Do you still get parallel execution building this way or are you stuck with one core?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to compile OpenCV 3.1 with the nonfree modules for Android and I got the message

`error: 'pthread_self' was not declared in this scope`

It was solved by including "ANDROID_NDK_LAYOUT" with value "RELEASE".

My CMake configuration:
[CMake configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvtJl.png)

I made a "mingw32-make clean" (just in case) and "mingw32-make"

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue so this question is actually valid and it makes me wonder why it got down-voted.

I am on windows10. After many tries, I solved this by simply downloading openCV-3.1.0 instead of 2.4.13.

Prior to moving to openCV-3.1.0, I tried installing code::blocks alone then installing the latest mingw version. Didn't help. I also tried generating the makefile using the 32 bit version of CMake vs the 64 bit version. Didn't help either.

With opencCV-3.1.0, you need not edit any .h files like I read elsewhere. Expect a longer mingw32-make execution time too.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 with openCV-3.2.0. also having this problem.  Do I need to go back to 3.1.0 to make this work? (I would have thought that it would continue working on the later version that I have.)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the `pthread_self` error by unchecking `WITH_PTHREADS_PF` in CMake

Comment: Do you still get parallel execution (presumably with something other than pthreads) or does this cause it to run on one core?